Get all data from the range of date including no record
Let say I have below table:



Date
Group Name
Employee




2024-11-01
Group A
John


2024-11-01
Group A
Rachel


2024-11-01
Group B
Mary


2024-11-02
Group A
John


2024-11-03
Group A
Rachel


2024-11-03
Group B
Mary


2024-11-05
Group A
John


2024-11-05
Group B
Mary



Using below query but the group name return as null.

with scheduler as (
  select convert(datetime, '2024-11-05 00:00:00', 120) as 'dt' -- end date
  union all
  select  dateadd(DAY, -1, dt) from scheduler 
  where dateadd(dd, -1, dt) >= convert(datetime, '2024-11-01 00:00:00', 120) -- start date
)
select convert(date, a.dt) as 'date', b.group_name, b.employee 
from scheduler a
left join tbl_a b
order by a.dt, b.group_name;





Date
Group Name
Employee




2024-11-01
Group A
John


2024-11-01
Group A
Rachel


2024-11-01
Group B
Mary


2024-11-02
Group A
John


2024-11-03
Group A
Rachel


2024-11-03
Group B
Mary


2024-11-04
NULL
NULL


2024-11-05
Group A
John


2024-11-05
Group B
Mary



I'm expecting below result:



Date
Group Name
Employee




2024-11-01
Group A
John


2024-11-01
Group A
Rachel


2024-11-01
Group B
Mary


2024-11-02
Group A
John


2024-11-02
Group B
NULL


2024-11-03
Group A
Rachel


2024-11-03
Group B
Mary


2024-11-04
Group A
NULL


2024-11-04
Group B
NULL


2024-11-05
Group A
John


2024-11-05
Group B
Mary




You also need to join on a list of all possible groups if you want to get those results, in the same way you are creating a list of all possible dates. If you are not sure how to do that, please explain how to obtain a complete list of all possible groups.

include all groups into join e.g. from scheduler a cross join (select distinct group_name from tbl_a) as g left join tbl_a as d on a.date = d.date and g.group_name = d.group_name  the cross join then produces every date with every group, the left join matches to existing data and you get NULL when the data does not match

If you select the group nam from the group cross join it will never be null

@PaulMaxwell it's working well, just notice i used select d.group_name instead of select g.group_name. thanks a lot!

@DaleK got it. thanks for the hint!

To guarantee that every group name is present for every date, you can build a list of distinct group names and include them using a cross-join in your query before the left-join.
with scheduler as (
  select convert(datetime, '2024-11-05 00:00:00', 120) as 'dt' -- end date
  union all
  select  dateadd(DAY, -1, dt) from scheduler 
  where dateadd(dd, -1, dt) >= convert(datetime, '2024-11-01 00:00:00', 120) -- start date
),
groups as (
    select distinct group_name
    from employee_group
)
select convert(date, s.dt) as 'date', g.group_name, e.employee 
from scheduler s
cross join groups g 
left join employee_group e
    on e.date = s.dt
    and e.group_name = g.group_name
order by s.dt, g.group_name, e.employee;

You could also just inline the distinct group name subquery if you prefer:
cross join (select distinct group_name from employee_group) g 

(I took the liberty of giving your source data a meaningful name and changing the table aliases.)
Results:



date
group_name
employee




2024-11-01
Group A
John


2024-11-01
Group A
Rachel


2024-11-01
Group B
Mary


2024-11-02
Group A
John


2024-11-02
Group B
null


2024-11-03
Group A
Rachel


2024-11-03
Group B
Mary


2024-11-04
Group A
null


2024-11-04
Group B
null


2024-11-05
Group A
John


2024-11-05
Group B
Mary



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

it's working!!!! thanks so much

I think, that is better include group_name to sheduler.
See example



dt
Group_name
Employee




2024-11-01
Group A
John


2024-11-01
Group A
Rachelv


2024-11-01
Group B
Mary


2024-11-02
Group A
John


2024-11-03
Group A
Rachel


2024-11-03
Group B
Mary


2024-11-05
Group A
John


2024-11-05
Group B
Mary



with r as(
  select distinct group_name,cast('2024-11-01' as date) dt,cast('2024-11-05' as date)to_dt
  from tbl_a
  union all 
  select group_name,dateadd(day,1,dt) dt,to_dt
  from r
  where dt<to_dt
)
select r.group_name,r.dt,a.employee 
from r
left join tbl_a a on a.group_name=r.group_name and a.dt=r.dt
order by r.dt,r.group_name;




group_name
dt
employee




Group A
2024-11-01
John


Group A
2024-11-01
Rachelv


Group B
2024-11-01
Mary


Group A
2024-11-02
John


Group B
2024-11-02
null


Group A
2024-11-03
Rachel


Group B
2024-11-03
Mary


Group A
2024-11-04
null


Group B
2024-11-04
null


Group A
2024-11-05
John


Group B
2024-11-05
Mary



fiddle

This is similar to the other answers except that it's 100% self-configuring.  It figures out what the min and max dates are as well as the set of unique Group Names. They don't need to be provided.
First, here's the test data that I used.  It came from the "table" that the OP posted. I preserved the use of "Date", which is a reserved word that shouldn't be used. I also preserved the space in "Group Name", which should also not be used.  It would be nice if people asking the questions would post the example data in such a readily consumable form as this...
--===== Drop the test table to make reruns easier
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable;
GO
--===== Create and populate the test table on the fly
 SELECT  [Date] = CONVERT(DATE,v.Date) --Date is a reserved word. Should be changed.
        ,v.[Group Name] --The OP had a space in the original like this
        ,v.Employee
   INTO #TestTable
   FROM (VALUES
         ('2024-11-01','Group A','John'  )
        ,('2024-11-01','Group A','Rachel')
        ,('2024-11-01','Group B','Mary'  )
        ,('2024-11-02','Group A','John'  )
        ,('2024-11-03','Group A','Rachel')
        ,('2024-11-03','Group B','Mary'  )
        ,('2024-11-05','Group A','John'  )
        ,('2024-11-05','Group B','Mary'  )
        )v([Date], [Group Name], Employee)
;

Here's the code to solve the problem.  Each CTE has a short comment to explain it's purpose.
WITH
 cteGroupName AS
(--==== Get the unique group names
 SELECT DISTINCT [Group Name] 
   FROM #TestTable
)
,cteDateRange AS
(--===== Get the min and max dates of all the dates
 SELECT  MinDate = MIN([Date])
        ,MaxDate = MAX([Date])
   FROM #TestTable
)
,cteAllDatesGroups AS
(--==== Create a "master" control set of all dates and groups
 SELECT  [Date]       = DATEADD(dd,t.N,dr.MinDate)
        ,[Group Name] = gn.[Group Name]
   FROM cteDateRange dr
  CROSS JOIN cteGroupName gn
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTally(0,DATEDIFF(dd,dr.MinDate,dr.MaxDate))t
)--==== Left Join the Employee name to the "master" control set
     -- to include missing dates and groups
 SELECT adg.[Date], adg.[Group Name], src.Employee
   FROM cteAllDatesGroups adg
   LEFT JOIN #TestTable   src  ON adg.[Date]       = src.[Date] 
                              AND adg.[Group Name] = src.[Group Name]
  ORDER BY [Date], [Group Name], Employee --Order by sorts the result!
;

Here are the results... I've highlighted the rows that were missing from the data that are now present.

And here's the code for the fnTally function (right after the "p.s." below.  If you have SQL Server 2022, you could use the "new" GENERATE_SERIES() function as a replacement.
p.s. It's a really bad idea to use a Recursive CTE to create a sequence like they did in the other code answers.  The long story made shorter is that produce 8 times the number of reads as a WHILE loop and they take longer to run.
Here's an article on the subject if you want more information...
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnTally
/**********************************************************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Given a starting value of "0" or "1" and a max positive value <= 2,147,483,647, return the range of whole numbers
 from the start value to the max value.

 This is just one version of the "dbo.fnTally" function. This one is based on 16 original values. It has exactly the
 same functionality as other versions.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Usage:
--===== Basic syntax example
 SELECT N FROM dbo.fnTally(@ZeroOrOne,@MaxN);

--===== Return values from 0 to 1000
 SELECT N FROM dbo.fnTally(0,1000);

--===== Return values from 1 to 1000
 SELECT N FROM dbo.fnTally(1,1000);
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1. This code works for SQL Server 2008 and up.
 2. Based on Itzik Ben-Gan's cascading CTE (cCTE) method for creating a "readless" Tally Table source of BIGINTs.
    Refer to the following URL for how it works.
    https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers
 3. This code only uses 7 "Nested Loops" instead of 31
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - Unknown     - Jeff Moden 
        - Initial creation with error handling for @MaxN.
 Rev 01 - 09 Feb 2013 - Jeff Moden 
        - Modified to start at 0 or 1 and removed error handling for @MaxN.
**********************************************************************************************************************/
        (@ZeroOrOne TINYINT, @MaxN BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
 RETURN WITH
   E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))E0(N))
             SELECT N = 0 WHERE @ZeroOrOne = 0 UNION ALL   --May or may not be present as a row in the return
             SELECT TOP(@MaxN)
                    N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
               FROM E1 a,E1 b,E1 c,E1 d,E1 e,E1 f,E1 g,E1 h         --1 to 16^8 or 4,294,967,296 rows max
              ORDER BY N
;
GO

